Javascript Intl.NumberFormat for fr-ch locale and currency CHF wrong output in new safari browser
For the below code in safari version 17 getting the output has "CHF 123 456,79" but for version safari version 16 it is giving the output "123 456,79 CHF"
, in chrome browser it is giving the output"123 456,79 CHF" dose anyone know why
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-ch', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF' }).format(
    number,
  ),
);


How can i add code a formatting patch
